# How to Split a folder with multiple dataset into train and test using PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, ecgi

I have a folder with 48 ECG signal files. The files include .dat and .atr ECG signal records and annotation. I want to split them to train and test to train the AI model. I will be using PyTorch and I want to know a simple way to do this in Python.I prefer a custom split with certain number of files to be in train and the rest in test.

Eg: Train : ['101', '104','107']
Test : ['102', '105','106']

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here first you need to store the Input and attribute location using
a dictionary in python with Input file name as key and Attribute file name as Value.

Then you can split the key of the dictionary and use that as input.

```
from glob import glob

MainFolder="<Your Folder Name>"

Data={}
for file in glob(MainFolder+"/*.dat"):
   At_file=file[:-3]+"atr"
   Data[file]=At_file

# Here Data would have Input and attribute file name as key and value pair

# To split the date: 

Key_data=list(Data)
import random
random.shuffle(Key_data)

#Here you specify the split ratio of Training and Testing
split=int(len(Key_data)*(0.8))

Train_in=Key_data[:split]
Test_in=Key_data[split:]
Train_at=[Data[i] for i in Train_in]
Test_at=[Data[i] for i in Test_in]

print(Train_in,Train_at,Test_in,Test_at)
```

Here Train_in is the Input files and Train_at is its corresponding attribute files

This should solve your problem. Comment if you get any error in implementing the above code.

Comment: Thank you, Kalyan. The code works. However, it only splits the .dat files. not the annotation files(.atr)  . This is the dataset I am trying to use --> https://physionet.org/content/mitdb/1.0.0/

Comment: @Fathima You can get the annotation file name using Data dictionary, ex: Data[i] where i is element in the Train or Test list. I think this would answer you question. Do accept and Upvote the answer if this solves your problem.

Comment: @Fathima See the edits, I printed both Input and attribute files, But I recommned you to use the Train_in list and while you iterate over Train_in during training use the Data[i] to get the corresponding attribute for the element in Train_in.

Comment: @Fathima Do mark the answer as correct if it answers your question and upvote if you like it :))